# How to find rows that have specific difference between two rows

Tags: sql

Consider the table

```
ID     Value
1       3
2       4
3       6
4       7
5       8
6      11
7      12
```

I want to find rows where the difference between two subsequent Values is different than 1.

Id = 2 has Value = 4 and Id = 3 has Value = 6, difference in Value between these two rows is 2, which is different than 1. As a return I want this table

```
Id    Difference
2     2
5     3
```

I am using MySQL (SQL available at cPanel).

I could not find a solution to this problem anywhere.

Comment: Your question isn't super clear, but have you tried `where value - id > 1`

Comment: @Isolated You did not understand my question.  Id = 2 has Value = 4 and Id = 3 has Value = 6, difference in Value between these two rows is 2, which is different than 1.  I want Ids (2, 5) and the differences returned (2, 3).

Comment: I still don't understand the question.  How are (2,5) related to (2,3) ??

Also, you will want to specify which RDBMS you are using, are if you are targeting a specific level of SQL.  There are significant differences between various SQLs and their capabilities.

Comment: So based on your sample data, are those the only combinations you want to return? Do you only care about ID 2 and ID 3? What about id 7 compared to id 5,4,3,2,1?

Comment: @Isolated I am always comparing two subsequent rows and their Values.  If the difference is different than 1, I want to know it.

Comment: @Isolated Let me put this way.  The program reads sensor every second and puts the reading time in Value.  But sometimes program cannot read the sensor and does not put anything in table.  I want to know when the program failed to read the sensor and how long it was unable to read the sensor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easily solved by using *lead* or *lag* windows:

```
with diff as (
  select * , Abs(value -  lead(value) over(order by id)) diff
  from t
)
select *
from diff
where diff > 1;
```

See [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/MaVvp22_)

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I am looking for. By googling I found out that I need LEAD, but I did not know how to use SQL synthax. I have no experience with SQL at all.  To be precise, it should be "where diff != 1" and "abs" in not necessary,

Comment: Lead is one way, others are possible like with most things, eg compare the current value to a correlated subquery retrieving the limit 1 of the table where the ID is greater than the current ID.

Answer (score 0):

This also gives the solution without using windows function like 'LAG'

```
 SELECT v1. id, v2.value - v1.value AS difference
 FROM Mytable v1 JOIN MyTable v2 ON v1.id = (v2.id)-1
 WHERE ABS(v1.value - v2.value) <> 1;
```